How to query a table that has a many to many relationship using SQLAlchemy, FastAPI, Pydantic, Postgres and field that is a Mapped[List[Obj]]?
I have been going at this for 4 days and I really need some help.  As Discussed in the title, I am using Python, SQLAlchemy, PostgreSQL, FastAPI, and Pydantic ( among other things ).  I am getting tuples back and I don't understand what is happening.  Also I am just now seeing that it is the repr in the tuple... hmmm.
I have defined the Models for Buyer, HSCode, and BuyerHSCode for SQLAlchemy.
class Base(DeclarativeBase, AsyncAttrs):
    pass


class TimestampMixin(object):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return cls.__name__.lower()

    created_at = mapped_column(DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
    updated_at = mapped_column(
        DateTime, nullable=False, server_default=func.now(), onupdate=func.now()
    )

class Buyer(Base, TimestampMixin):
    __tablename__ = "buyers"

    uid: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        pg.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, nullable=False
    )
    company_name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    region: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(15), nullable=False)
    country: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(56), nullable=False)
    city: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(100), nullable=False)
    company_size: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(30), nullable=False)

    hs_codes: Mapped[List["HSCode"]] = relationship("HSCode", secondary='buyer_hs_codes', back_populates="buyers")

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<Buyer(company_name='{self.company_name}')>"

class HSCode(Base):
    __tablename__ = "hs_codes"

    uid: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        pg.UUID(as_uuid=True), primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, nullable=False
    )
    hs_code: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(12), nullable=False)

    buyers: Mapped[List["Buyer"]] = relationship("Buyer", secondary='buyer_hs_codes', back_populates="hs_codes")

class BuyerHSCode(Base):
    __tablename__ = "buyer_hs_codes"

    buyer_uid: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        pg.UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('buyers.uid'), primary_key=True
    )
    hs_code_uid: Mapped[uuid.UUID] = mapped_column(
        pg.UUID(as_uuid=True), ForeignKey('hs_codes.uid'), primary_key=True
    )

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<BuyerHSCode(buyer_id='{self.buyer_uid}', hs_code_id='{self.hs_code_uid}')>"

I have created multiple Classes to represent the data in a Pythonic way.
class BuyerResponseModel(BaseModel):
    company_name: str
    region: str
    country: str
    city: str
    company_size: str
    hs_codes: List[HSCodeResponse]
    created_at: str
    updated_at: str

    class Config:
        from_attributes = True

class HSCodeResponse(BaseModel):
    hs_code: str


I have created the FastAPI endpoint along with a Class to represent all the services for the buyer endpoints.
@buyer_router.get("/", response_model=List[BuyerResponseModel])
async def get_all_buyers_endpoint(session: AsyncSession = Depends(get_session)):
    return await buyer_service.get_all_buyers(session)

async def get_all_buyers(self, session: AsyncSession):
    statement = (
        select(Buyer)
        .options(selectinload(Buyer.hs_codes))
        .order_by(desc(Buyer.created_at))
    )

    result = await session.exec(statement)
    buyers = result.all()

        return buyers

Error when using FastAPI Docs:
fastapi.exceptions.ResponseValidationError: 8 validation errors:
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'company_name'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'region'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'country'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'city'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'company_size'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'hs_codes'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'created_at'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}
  {'type': 'missing', 'loc': ('response', 0, 'updated_at'), 'msg': 'Field required', 'input': (<Buyer(company_name='company1')>,)}

Terminal Output:
2024-10-18 10:31:54,924 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-10-18 10:31:54,931 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT buyers.uid, buyers.company_name, buyers.region, buyers.country, buyers.city, buyers.company_size, buyers.created_at, buyers.updated_at 
FROM buyers ORDER BY buyers.created_at DESC
2024-10-18 10:31:54,931 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00051s] ()
2024-10-18 10:31:54,952 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT buyers_1.uid AS buyers_1_uid, hs_codes.uid AS hs_codes_uid, hs_codes.hs_code AS hs_codes_hs_code 
FROM buyers AS buyers_1 JOIN buyer_hs_codes AS buyer_hs_codes_1 ON buyers_1.uid = buyer_hs_codes_1.buyer_uid JOIN hs_codes ON hs_codes.uid = buyer_hs_codes_1.hs_code_uid 
WHERE buyers_1.uid IN ($1::UUID)
2024-10-18 10:31:54,952 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00045s] (UUID('70bd135d-841c-49c6-997d-da18d3b34e4a'),)
2024-10-18 10:31:54,966 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50269 - "GET /api/v1/buyers/ HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error

here is what FastAPI Docs expects for the endpoint...
[
  {
    "company_name": "string",
    "region": "string",
    "country": "string",
    "city": "string",
    "company_size": "string",
    "hs_codes": [
      {
        "hs_code": "string"
      }
    ],
    "created_at": "string",
    "updated_at": "string"
  }
]

Please feel free to ask any questions for clarification.  I am new to FastAPI, SQLAlchemy, and PostgreSQL.  I normally work with Flask and create all of this myself but I am at a total loss and really need some help.  Thank you.

What does buyers.all() actually return?

It would be returning a list of json objects. M.O. has helped with the session.scalars() suggestion.  and thank you @Kirill for editing the error outputs to make my post more palatable.

SQLAlchemy will return a list of Row objects, which are essentially length 1 tuples in this case. To make it return just a list of Buyers, the easiest way is to replace session.exec(statement) with session.scalars(statement).

@ M.O.  I appreciate that and the suggestions worked.  I was going in circles due to being warned that session.execute() was depreciated and suggesting i go with session.exec() and then getting warnings about scalars.  Thank you for taking the time to read all the code i presented and give me an answer.

No worries! I've done the same mistake several times. I would still recommend running session.execute() and session.scalars() just to compare the differences.

just to further this, I was using a combination of sqlmodel asyncsession and sqlalchemy, so that is why when i was attempting to use execute in the first place, pycharm was striking execute through and saying it was depreciated.  I hate any type of warnings in my code so i just followed its advice.  I just now converted everything to sqlalchemy and getting rid of sqlmodel.  Thank you again @M.O.!
